Using different stripe accounts for different subscriptions
I am making a payment site where I need to recieve payments from customers using stripe.
Problems:

We are using two stripe accounts one for a base subscription and one is an addon subscription which is for a second business but we want it to be user friendly so we want to capture card information once for the both businesses and just based on a checkbox we want to trigger payments for the individual businesses.
The stripe prop once initialized on ReactJS once can not be changed at all.
In the backend the one payment method ID generated can not be used for the second at all.

I am using Node Express for backend and ReactJS for frontend.

You haven't provided enough information.  Why are you using multiple Stripe accounts?  Are you using Stripe Connect? What exactly does "addon subscription" mean?

I am not using stripe connect just two different accounts and two different accounts to be charged seperately one is a base subscription charged to one account and when addon is selected, base+addon both are charged seperately but the card input should be one and it should be seamless.

That's not possible.  If you're not using Stripe Connect then two different Stripe accounts are going to be entirely isolated from each other with no way to use the same payment info across both.
